# jquery asynchronous dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

Are the `jquery` modal dialogs asynchronous?

```
$('.triage').click(function() {

                 $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                        position: [175, 175],
                        draggable: false,
         height: 140,
         modal: true

            });
        });

        $.ajax(
                 {
                 type: "POST",
                 data: [],
                 dataType: "json",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 url: "ReferralAutoTriage.asmx/RunTriageReferrals",
                 success: function(response) {
                      $("#dialog-modal").dialog('close')                               

                },
                failure: function(response) {
                                        }
            });


    });
```

If the dialog is synchronous I need to make it asynchronous, so I can process ajax call while displaying dialog and close after I am done with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `beforeSend`/`complete` events to display/hide your dialog.

```
$('.triage').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: [],
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ReferralAutoTriage.asmx/RunTriageReferrals",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                position: [175, 175],
                draggable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true
            });
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // whatever
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            // whatever
        },
        complete: function() {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog('close');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It think you mean "blocking," not "synchronous," in which case - no, jQuery modal dialogs are not blocking. Only browser-native `alert()`, `confirm()`, and `prompt()` dialogs can do that.

You can absolutely process ajax calls which a modal dialog is open.

---

It sounds like you're trying to figure out why your code isn't working. How about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) via http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com?

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, I wasn't trying to debug the code, still in design phase and was just curious about that